# SQL Server Profiler suddenly says Encrypted Text

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, profiler

Recently I noticed that a stored proc we are trying to profile failed to appear in the profiling output.

After adding in SP:StmtStarting and SP:StmtCompleted events, I noticed the TextData reported as

```
-- Encrypted text
```

.. but the stored procedure is not encrypted.

This has only recently started happening - we used to profile this SP perfectly fine, and I can't figure what has changed.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

UPDATE: The SP is definitely not encrypted. I've created new SP's on the box, and I see SP:BatchStarting event with the new SP's name. With the old SP, I don't see the BatchStarting event, but I do see the statements within the SP executing.

However I need to see the values of the parameters the SP is being called with, as they are table types. Originally I could see the table types being instantiated and populated before the SP is called.

Comment: How have you verified "the stored procedure is not encrypted"?

Comment: Viewing the properties of the SP and ensuring Encyrpted = False

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured this out in case anyone finds it useful.

I have table type parameters to this stored procedure. One of the parameters is passed a lot of data (i.e. a C# DataTable with >5000 rows). Without this quantity of data the stored proc profiled fine.

I guess there must be some cut-off at which point Profiler does not show all of the data being passed in.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the same behaviour when using table types. I am thinking that "encrypted text" here doesn't really mean encrypted but rather compressed.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has altered the stored procedure and added the 'WITH ENCRYPTION' hint, which will cause this behavior.  Alter the stored procedure and remove that hint and you'll start seeing the text of the proc again.

Also to note, if you don't have the original code, you will not be able to decrypt the text of the proc to issue the ALTER statement, so hopefully you have that handy.

Here's a decent run down of this option: [Options for hiding SQL Server code](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1828/options-for-hiding-sql-server-code/)

Comment: Another possibility - depending on the version of SQL Server - is that the text of the procedure has been changed to include `sp_password`, which *used to* automatically cause traces to obfuscate the text.

Comment: @Jason - The SP is not encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the Trace Properties from the default of `OnlySP(<your database here>)(user,default)` to `TSQL` or `TSQL_Replay` unveiled the SQL being used for me, ...  Go to `File|Properties...` and change the [Use the template:] drop-down combobox.[image: SQL Server Profiler|Trace Properties Dialog]

Comment: Not sure if anything changed since this post, but with SQL Server 2019 and SQL Profiler v18.6 (and at least on my machine) the TSQL template does not show the TextData for params sent to SP's. TSQL_Replay does the trick (including data added to table type params).